# Unable to get the required redirect_uri in react-facebook-login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, facebook-authentication

I'm trying to implement the Facebook OAuth in my express/NodeJS app using authorization code flow. I'm using react-facebook-login node module to fetch the authorization code. In my react app, I could get the authorization code successfully. But in server side, I can't request the access token from the Facebook API as I'm getting an error message "redirect_uri is not identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

Code in my react app,

```
facebookLogin = async (signedRequest) => {
    return fetch('/api/auth/facebook', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ signedRequest }),
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(res);
      }
    });
  };

  responseFacebook = async (response) => {
    try {
      if (response['signedRequest']) {
        const userProfile = await this.facebookLogin(response['signedRequest']);
        console.log(userProfile);
      } else {
        throw new Error(response.error);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

render() {
    <FacebookLogin
            appId={process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}
            fields="name,email"
            responseType="code"
            redirectUri="http://localhost:3000/"
            callback={this.responseFacebook}
    />
```

In my app.js

```
const facebookOAuth = require('./config/facebookOAuth');

// facebook oauth route
app.post("/api/auth/facebook", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const signedRequest = req.body.signedRequest;
    const profile = await facebookOAuth.getProfile(signedRequest);
    console.log(profile);

    res.send({ profile });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(401).send();
  }
});
```

facebookOAuth.js look like this

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const getData = async (userId, accessToken) => {
    const userData = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/${userId}?fields=name,email&access_token=${accessToken}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((userData) => {
        return userData;
    });

    return userData;
};

exports.getProfile = async (signedRequest) => {
    const decodedSignedRequest = JSON.parse(Buffer.from((signedRequest.split(".")[1]), 'base64').toString());
    const profile = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=${process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent('http://localhost:3000/')}&client_secret=${process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET}&code=${decodedSignedRequest.code}`, {
        method: 'GET'
    }).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((token) => {
        console.log(token);
        const userData = getData(decodedSignedRequest.user_id, token.access_token);
        return userData;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    });

    return profile;
}
```

What I'm getting is this error

```
"error": {
      message: 'Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request',
      type: 'OAuthException',
      code: 100,
      error_subcode: 36008,
      fbtrace_id: 'A-YAgSqKbzPR94XL8QjIyHn'
}
```

I think the problem lies in my redirect_uri. Apparently, the redirect uri I obtained from the Facebook auth dialog is different from the one that I'm passing to the facebook API in my server side (http://localhost:3000/).

I believe there's something to do with the origin parameter of the redirect_uri. Initial auth dialog request uri indicates that it's origin parameter value is something like "origin=localhost:3000/f370b6cb4b5a9c". I don't know why react-facebook-login add some sort of trailing value at the end of origin param.

[https://web.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?app_id=249141440286033&auth_type=&cbt=1620173773354&channel_url=https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f39300d6265e5c4&domain=localhost&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ff370b6cb4b5a9c&relation=opener&client_id=249141440286033&display=popup&domain=localhost&e2e={}&fallback_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&locale=en_US&logger_id=f1b3fba38c5e31c&origin=1&redirect_uri=https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f17641be4cce4d4&domain=localhost&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ff370b6cb4b5a9c&relation=opener&frame=f3960892790a6d4&response_type=token,signed_request,graph_domain&return_scopes=false&scope=public_profile,email&sdk=joey&version=v2.3](https://web.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?app_id=249141440286033&auth_type=&cbt=1620173773354&channel_url=https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f39300d6265e5c4&domain=localhost&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ff370b6cb4b5a9c&relation=opener&client_id=249141440286033&display=popup&domain=localhost&e2e=%7B%7D&fallback_redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&locale=en_US&logger_id=f1b3fba38c5e31c&origin=1&redirect_uri=https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=f17641be4cce4d4&domain=localhost&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Ff370b6cb4b5a9c&relation=opener&frame=f3960892790a6d4&response_type=token,signed_request,graph_domain&return_scopes=false&scope=public_profile,email&sdk=joey&version=v2.3)

I tried finding everywhere about this but no luck. Anyone has clue about this, much appreciated.

Comment: And also, I have added http://localhost:3000 as valid oauth redirect uri in facebook app dashboard.

Comment: Just FYI, to use environment variables in react that exist in the final bundle you need to prefix them with `REACT_APP_`

Comment: Sure, thank you for that

Comment: This is completely working if I use access token and user id from client side instead of authorization code. I wondering why it is not working as we supposed to use auth code rather than access token from client side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using middleware to parse the body? if you aren't code could be undefined here.

```js
const facebookOAuth = require('./config/facebookOAuth');

// facebook oauth route
app.post("/api/auth/facebook", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const code = req.body.code;
    const profile = await facebookOAuth.getProfile(code);
    console.log(profile);
    res.send({ profile });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(401).send();
  }
});
```

Comment: And you're certain your configured app matches protocol, host and port?

Comment: Yes, I have added http://localhost:3000 as valid oauth redirect uri in facebook app

Comment: You double check your client secret?

Comment: I tried switching the app to 'in development' mode. But it keep asking me for valid Privacy Policy URL and data deletion information. As I'm using localhost, what should I provide for this?

Comment: That shouldn't affect you. It starts in development mode. You need those documents before leaving it. Just finished flipping through your code and I think I know the issue.

Comment: I'm using body parser. And I checked, the authorization code is receiving properly in the server side.